# Authentication error nodemailer when using Mandrill as SMTP provider

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am trying to send email by using nodemailer in my nodejs application. I tried to send with gmail and everything was ok but when I use Mandrill as my SMTP provider I got an Authentication error.

here is my code:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Mandrill",
    auth: {
        user: "username@mydomain.com",
        pass: "*****"
    }
});

module.exports.sendEmail = function(to, subject, body, callback){
    smtpTransport.sendMail({
        from: "username@mydomain.com",
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        html: body
    }, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log(error); callback(error, response);
        }else{
            callback(null, response);
        }
    });
};

};
```

and thats the error I got

```
{ [AuthError: Invalid login - 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed:]
    name: 'AuthError',
        data: '435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed:',
    stage: 'auth' }
```

Comment: I am using Mac OS X @Vinz243

Comment: Have you tried in VirtualBox (unix) or using C9.io?

Comment: No I havent and why should I use Virtual Box ?

Comment: To virtalize *nix environnement. I remember that Direct transport wasn't working with windows whereas it worked in c9.io.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem. In my case the authentication error was because mandrill does not accept your mandrill account password as the smtp authentication password, rather an api key which you can generate on your dashboard. The username is the same as you account username. The misconception arises probably because of the examples on mandrill's home-page, but it is explicitly mentioned under the SMTP & API credentials page (once you login) that smtp password is an api key.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Yup. Just to elaborate the code looks like:

`var transport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
   service: 'Mandrill',
   auth: {
     user: 'admin@mixmax.com',
     pass: '1NAkHCOllEE4*****'
   }
});`